# Completing the character table

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G=\{a,b|a^6=1,a^3=b^2,b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\}$ be a group of order 12. $G$ has 6 conjugacy classes $$\{1\},\{a^3\},\{a,a^{-1}\},\{a^2,a^{-2}\},\{b,a^2b,a^4b\},\{ab,a^3b,a^5b\}.$$ Name them $C_1$,...,$C_6$ in order given.
Complete the following character table:

[image]